# How to load Stanfordnlp pipeline without printing the load processor messages

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, stanford-nlp

I am trying to get dependency relations for words using Stanfordnlp. I have downloaded the English models and able to load the models to get the dependency relations for the words in the text. However, it will also print the whole load process messages.

Sample code:

```py
import stanfordnlp

config = {
    'processors': 'tokenize,pos,lemma,depparse', # Comma-separated list of processors to use
    'lang': 'en', # Language code for the language to build the Pipeline in
    'tokenize_model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_tokenizer.pt', 
    'pos_model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_tagger.pt',
    'pos_pretrain_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt.pretrain.pt',
    'lemma_model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_lemmatizer.pt',
    'depparse_model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_parser.pt',
    'depparse_pretrain_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt.pretrain.pt'
}

text = 'The weather is nice today.'

# This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(**config) # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
doc = nlp(text)
doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()

>>>

Use device: cpu
---
Loading: tokenize
With settings: 
{'model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_tokenizer.pt', 'lang': 'en', 'shorthand': 'en_ewt', 'mode': 'predict'}
---
Loading: pos
With settings: 
{'model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_tagger.pt', 'pretrain_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt.pretrain.pt', 'lang': 'en', 'shorthand': 'en_ewt', 'mode': 'predict'}
---
Loading: lemma
With settings: 
{'model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_lemmatizer.pt', 'lang': 'en', 'shorthand': 'en_ewt', 'mode': 'predict'}
Building an attentional Seq2Seq model...
Using a Bi-LSTM encoder
Using soft attention for LSTM.
Finetune all embeddings.
[Running seq2seq lemmatizer with edit classifier]
---
Loading: depparse
With settings: 
{'model_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt_parser.pt', 'pretrain_path': 'C:\\path\\stanfordnlp_resources\\en_ewt_models\\en_ewt.pretrain.pt', 'lang': 'en', 'shorthand': 'en_ewt', 'mode': 'predict'}
Done loading processors!
---
('The', '2', 'det')
('weather', '4', 'nsubj')
('is', '4', 'cop')
('nice', '0', 'root')
('today', '4', 'obl:tmod')
('.', '4', 'punct')
```

I installed Stanfordnlp using Anaconda and working with Jupyter notebooks. Is there a way to skip the messages as I only need the dependencies.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to skip the messages. If you see the [code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp/blob/master/stanfordnlp/pipeline/core.py) (inside the Pipeline class), there is no parameter control to print it. Hence it will always print. See Line no. 104, 114, 117, 118.

Comment: @vb_rises Thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get rid of those lines in Jupyter notebooks, you can simply clear the outputs right after calling the pipeline;

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

...

nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(**config)
clear_output()
```